# iPhone SQLite Database not updating

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I just updated my sqlite database (added some new records) - saved it, reimported it into my Xcode project, and re-ran my app - all the new data showed up perfectly well on the iPhone Simulator as expected.

However, after installing the app on my iPhone, I'm still getting the *old* data that was bundled with the previous version of the app.
I of course deleted the older version of the app from the iPhone first, assuming it would thereby destroy its "Documents" folder and the older db file that was in it - but for some reason its still reading (or displaying) the old data - which doesn't make sense. Any ideas?

Comment: Debug it yourself and check which db its using for iPhone?

Comment: Did you clean the project (Cmd-K in Xcode)?

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting your device after you make database changes, and then seeing what sort of results you get.